# Как получить результат запроса COUNT(*)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Не знаю, откуда получить нужное мне значение. Метод ниже. Само задание:

> подсчитать максимальное количество повторений записей в поле Artist и
>   вывести его.

```
private void Count_Base()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=baza;Integrated Security=True";
    string sqlExpression = "SELECT Artist, COUNT(*) FROM Lab6 GROUP BY Artist";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = //от куда получить??? ;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во второй ячейке: `reader[1].`
Также можете дать ячейке имя, исправив запрос на

```
SELECT Artist, COUNT(*) as count FROM Lab6 GROUP BY Artist
```

и получить значение как `reader["count"]`.

Но учтите, что запрос вернет не одну строку, а много. Поэтому вы обойдете их все в цикле `while` (`reader.Read()`) и выведете в итоге только значение из последней строки.

Чтобы избежать этого ограничьте выборку одной строкой и отсортируйте данные как раз по второму столбцу в порядке убывания:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Artist, COUNT(*) FROM Lab6 GROUP BY Artist ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо - работает. Ответ отмечу

Answer (score 2):

`GetValue(0)`- повторяющаяся запись, `GetValue(1)` - количество повторений

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
```